# Send JSON data via POST (ajax); getting 403 from Shopify

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, shopify

I have the following code in my theme Snippets. It is called by a test page in my store, not an app. As far as I know, I don't need to take any auth steps. The code returns a 403 error. I can't figure out why.

```
$(document).ready(function () {

$("#process-all-products").click(function(e) {     
    e.preventDefault();
    var resultDiv = $("#resultDivContainer");
    var collection_id;
    var toAdd = new Array();
    for(i=0; i < length; i++){
        toAdd.push({
            variant_id: $("#variant-"+i).val(),        
            quantity_id: $("#quantity-"+i).val() || 0
        });
    }

  function createCollection(){
      var params = {
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/admin/custom_collections.json',
        data: { "custom_collection": { "title": "my_collection_title"  } },
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (response) {
            switch (response) {
                case true:
                    collection_id = response.id;
                    console.log("collection_id [" + collection_id + "]");
                    break;
                default:
                    resultDiv.html(response);
            }
        },            
        error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
          console.log("create collection failed!");
          alert(xhr.status);
          alert(thrownError);
        }
      };
      $.ajax(params);
  };
  createCollection();
});
});

</script>
```

Comment: A 403 error means you are not authorized to perform the request.  I don't see any authentication parameters in your request.

Answer (score 1):

> "A web server may return a 403 Forbidden HTTP status code in response to a request from a client  for a web page or resource to
>   indicate that the server can be reached and understood  the request,
>   but refuses to take any further action"

all HTTP request starting with 4** relate to serverside problems. 
In case of 403 you are not authorized.

You will have to supply authentication parameters to your request maybe like this:

https://serverfault.com/questions/371907/can-you-pass-user-pass-for-http-basic-authentication-in-url-parameters

hope this helped since from your code I can not come to any other answer

Answer (score 1):

You really don't want to do what you are trying to do the way you are trying to do it. Fundamentals at work here. In a Shopify store you are part of a public facing customer centric HTTP world. To call an /admin endpoint at any time requires authentication (log in to the store) or via an authenticated API call.

The only way to do an authenticated API call is with an authentication token. So if you are not logged in as an admin and you wanted to do that API call with Javascript, your API token would be visible to the public and then they could immediately do as they please with your store as per the tokens security settings, including possibly turning it into a gay pr0n emporium if they chose to.

Make an App. Do your job with the right tools.

Comment: I am logged in as an admin and I would be fine with this page being for admin use only. I want to keep it simple. I have never developed a Shopify app. Would prefer not to have to do that if there is a way to create an admin-only webpage that accomplishes my goal.